# Ganymed API: SFTP using

Tags: java, ssh, sftp

I am using the Ganymed API to sftp in to an Unix server . I am able to create the file in server, but the contents of the file is always empty.

Ganymed API location:
http://www.ganymed.ethz.ch/ssh2/

Code:

```
  function (ByteArrayOutputStream reportBytes){
 // reportBytes is a valid ByteArrayOutputStream
 // if I write it to a file in to a local directory using reportBytes.writeTo(fout); 
 // I can see the contents */

 byte byteArray[]=reportBytes.toByteArray();

 SFTPv3FileHandle SFTPFILEHandle=sftpClient.createFileTruncate("test.txt");
 //The file is created successfully and it is listed in unix 
 // The permissions of the file -rw-r--r-- 1 test.txt


 sftpClient.write(SFTPFILEHandle, 0, byteArray, 0,byteArray.length );
 //The above line doesnt seem to work, the file is always empty
 }

 /* write function definition is */
 public void write(SFTPv3FileHandle handle, long fileOffset, byte[] src, int srcoff, int len) throws IOException
```

Can someone tell me if I am doing something wrong here

Comment: Have you confirmed that you can upload files to this server by testing that with another SFTP client? Maybe your account has permissions to create files but not to write them...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I tried to solve your problem, and I ended up in the same situation, the created file remains empty.

However, I think I found the cause of the problem.

Here is an extract of the ch.ethz.ssh2.SFTPv3Client.write() method of ganymed API

```
    /**
 * Write bytes to a file. If <code>len</code> &gt; 32768, then the write operation will
 * be split into multiple writes.
 * 
 * @param handle a SFTPv3FileHandle handle.
 * @param fileOffset offset (in bytes) in the file.
 * @param src the source byte array.
 * @param srcoff offset in the source byte array.
 * @param len how many bytes to write.
 * @throws IOException
 */
public void write(SFTPv3FileHandle handle, long fileOffset, byte[] src, int srcoff, int len) throws IOException
{
    checkHandleValidAndOpen(handle);

    if (len < 0)

        while (len > 0)
        {
```

You see, when you send data to write, len is > 0, and because of the bogus condition, the method returns right away, and it never enters the while loop (that actually write something to the file).

I guess there was a statement right after the "if (len < 0)" before, but someone took it away and left us with useless piece of code...

**Update :**

Go get the latest version (The example above was using build 210). 
I had no problem with the build 250 and 251.

Here's my code, and it's writing correctly to a new file on my ssh server.

you will need to bulletproof this :)

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Connection conn = new Connection(hostname);
        conn.connect();
        boolean isAuthenticated = conn.authenticateWithPassword(username, password);

        if (isAuthenticated == false)
            throw new IOException("Authentication failed.");
        SFTPv3Client client = new SFTPv3Client(conn);
        File tmpFile = File.createTempFile("teststackoverflow", "dat");
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(tmpFile);
        fw.write("this is a test");
        fw.flush();
        fw.close();

        SFTPv3FileHandle handle = client.createFile(tmpFile.getName());
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(tmpFile); 
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int i=0;
                    long offset=0;
        while ((i = fis.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            client.write(handle,offset,buffer,0,i);
                            offset+= i;

        }
        client.closeFile(handle);
        if (handle.isClosed())  System.out.println("closed");;
        client.close();
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.. It was really frustrating trying to debug things in my code... You saved a lot of my time..Lesson learnt: Will have to look in API codes...Thanks for the code too, I will test that and let you know it if works.. Thanks !!!

Comment: The same code works perfect.. just had to change the version... Thanks  a ton !!

Comment: @Tony, I tried this out and it works great, but only if the file size is less than the buffer size (1024). This might help: after int i=0, add a long offset=0. Change the write statement to client.write(handle,offset,buffer,0,i); Then add a line offset+= i;

Answer (score 0):

Tony's answer above, with full class and  imports. You'll need to add ganymed and jsch jars:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

import ch.ethz.ssh2.Connection;
import ch.ethz.ssh2.SFTPv3Client;
import ch.ethz.ssh2.SFTPv3FileHandle;

public class GanyMedFTP {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Connection conn = new Connection("serverip");
        try {
            conn.connect();
            
            boolean isAuthenticated = conn.authenticateWithPassword("myusername", "mypassword");

            if (isAuthenticated == false)
                throw new IOException("Authentication failed.");
            SFTPv3Client client = new SFTPv3Client(conn);
            String fileName="OddyRoxxx.txt";
            File tmpFile = File.createTempFile(fileName, "dat");
             
            SFTPv3FileHandle handle = client.createFile(fileName);
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(tmpFile); 
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int i=0;
                        long offset=0;
            while ((i = fis.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                client.write(handle,offset,buffer,0,i);
                                offset+= i;

            }
            client.closeFile(handle);
            if (handle.isClosed())  System.out.println("closed");;
            client.close();
            
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        

    }

}
```